# How can I detect if device is an android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an android library for some common works. I used this library for phone apps. 
With android wear development, I can use same library on wear projects. But I need to detect if device is an android wear. I can send a parameter with context, like a boolean parameter named isWear ex... But I dont want to do like this. I couldn't find any sample code. How/where should I check on the device?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to check that? A wear app can only run on wear devices, no?

Comment: I have a library for phone and i want to use same library on wear project. @cricket_007

Comment: I can add a parameter like isWear ex... But I want that library can detect itself from context information.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Configuration`, the ui mode should have the right bit set:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH